# Closed convex set $C$ such that $C_{x} = C_{x'}$.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For any $x ∈ C$, define
$$C_{x} = \{y ∈ \mathbb{R}^{2}| x + ty ∈ C, ∀ t ≥ 0\}.$$
Prove that for any two points $x, x' ∈ C$, we have $C_{x} = C_{x'}$.

**My attempt:**

Let $x, x'\in C.$ We have $\lambda x + (1- \lambda) x' \in C, \forall 0< \lambda \leq 1.$

We fix a $\lambda$. Then $\exists x'' \in C$ such that $\lambda x + (1- \lambda) x' = x''.$

We express $x$ in terms of $x'$ and $x''$ as follows: $$ x = \frac{1}{\lambda}(x'' - (1-\lambda)x') $$
Now $y\in C_{x} \implies x+ty \in C$, $ \forall t\geq 0 \implies \frac{1}{\lambda}(x'' - (1-\lambda)x')  +ty \in C$, $\forall t\geq 0.$

From here I was thinking of somehow modifying $t$ to show that $x' +t'y\geq 0$, $\forall t'\geq 0$.

Am I going in the right direction or is there a different way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closedness of $C$ is essential and you are not using this property. You have to find  a sequence tending to $x'+ty$ such that each term belongs to $C$. Drawing a picture helps you to construct a proof.

Let $t \geq 0$ and  $x_n=(1-\frac t n) x'+\frac t n (x+ny)$. Then $x_n \to x'+ty$. If $y \in C_x$ then $x_n \in C$ for all $n$. Since $C$ is closed we see that $x'+ty \in C$. This proves that $C_x \subseteq C_{x'}$. Similarly $C_{x'}\subseteq C_{x}$.

Comment: This looks like one of those problems which are very easy but only after you realize what is to be done!